# Why do aldehydes polymerize faster in the cold?

Tags: kinetics, polymers

In amateur perfumery, raw chemicals are usually stored in sealed bottles in refrigerators/freezers to reduce decomposition rates. However, aldehydes are tricky to store for long periods of time because they tend to be reactive. The two biggest decomposition routes are oxidation (which can be prevented by having a good seal on containers) and oligo/polymerization.

Folk knowledge ([1, Pell Wall Perfume blog](http://pellwall-perfumes.blogspot.com/2013/02/aldehydes-identification-and-storage.html) and [2, Perfumery and Flavoring Synthetics by Bedoukian](http://www.panjora.com/books/perf_and_flav_synth/perf_and_flav_synth_pgs_019-025.htm) page 24) claims aldehydes polymerize more quickly in the cold, and so unlike most chemicals, perfumers are warned to store aldehydes at room temperature, rather than frozen.

Why do aldehydes polymerize faster in the cold?

From thermodynamics, it makes sense polymerization occurs *to greater completion* in the cold, since polymerization is usually exothermic, so Le Châtelier's implies the cold will drive the reaction to the right. Likewise, since polymerization has $\Delta S <0$, cooling below the polymer ceiling temperature $T_c=\Delta H/\Delta S$ causes polymerization to be spontaneously possible.

However, I can't find any mechanistic explanation of why the *rate* increases in the cold, or even any other sources besides an online blog and a perfumery textbook which back up this claim. Can any polymer fans explain why cold is bad for aldehydes?

Comment: Note that "they [aldehydes] polymerizes quicker" does not mean that their rate of polymerization increases. It just means that "their rate of polymerization increases" COMPARED to another rate when the temperature diminishes.

Comment: In chemistry labs, aldehydes are typically stored as cold as possible: the more stable ones in the fridge, everything else in the freezer. This kind of contradicts your sources’ statement.